# why components render when use `setState` to store new value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

In react, we commonly use the `useState` hook to store data. We don't update the state directly, because the component doesn't re-render in this way. Now my question is, How did `setState` trigger the rendering under the hood?

A common concept can be `setState` call the rendering. But I think maybe there is something else. (something global object or state obj manipulation, something like this).

I don't understand how to `setState` trigger rendering under the hood. If anyone can explain it, it will be very helpful for me including others.

Comment: That's a common question. Yes, React is simply a library, it's not a magic tool. By the way, this is all explained in the docs.

Comment: might help: https://overreacted.io/how-does-setstate-know-what-to-do/